# Rank of the matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I want to ask, if rank of matrix with right side (Ab=3), is greater than the rank of the matrix without it (A=2) does it mean that matrix does not have solution?

Thanks

Comment: What? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "equal sign" in $A=2$ and $Ab=3$ ?

Comment: I mean that the rank of matrix A is equal to 2, and the rank of matrix Ab is equal to 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to determine whether there are no solutions, a unique solution or infinite many solutions, use the following conditions :

$1)$ The matrix $A$ and the matrix emerging by concatenating $A$ and $b$ must have the same rank. If this is not the case, there is no solution. If it is the case, then continue with $2)$

$2)$ If the rank of the matrix $A$ is equal to the number of unknowns, the solution is unique, otherwise there are infinite many solutions.

Comment: Wow, talking about mind reading...

Comment: I remembered this condition and it seemed to fit the description of the question. I agree, it could have been formulated clearer in the question.

Comment: thanks, I did, sorry for my english.. in which case it would have infinite number of solutions?

Comment: If the rank is equal to the number of unknowns, the solution is unique, otherwise there are infinite many solutions.

Comment: I think you could add some explanations to your answer...

Comment: Okay, but how I know if  it has infinite many solutions or none? Because in the case, which I unclearly explain above, the number of unknowns could be 3 and rank of the matrix is 2.. so what is the difference?

Comment: First verify whether the ranks coincide (if not, there is no solution), then verify whether the rank is equal to the number of unknowns. My comment assumed that we already found out that there is a solution.

Comment: So, when the rank of matrix A is equal to 3, and the rank of matrix Ab is equal to 3 but numbers of unknowns is 4, I have infinite number of solutions?

Comment: Yes, because you have more unknowns than the rank of the matrix.

Comment: @JeanMarie better ?

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Shelley I edited my answer , do you agree it is now better formulated ?

Comment: @Peter Better ! But I think it is valuable to explain this necessary and sufficient condition by saying that a vector $b$ belongs to the range of $A$ iff it can be written $\sum_k b_k A_k$ (where the $A_k$s are the columns of $A$, and the latter expression is nothing else than $Ab$ where $b$ is the vector with entries $b_k$.

Comment: @JeanMarie To be honest, I never asked me why this condition is necessary and sufficient. You can formulate an own answer , if you want. I will upvote it :)

Comment: @Peter Yes, I understand it fully, thanks :)